Vue Vite Vuestic Validate Rules on Nested Child Component
Here I have structure like this
DivisiSalesForm.vue call Step1DivisiSales.vue call CompanySelect.vue
The submit button is on DivisiSalesForm.vue and I want to validate all the input on Step1DivisiSales.vue before submitting the data.
I already give rules on CompanySelect.vue but it won't works, only the VaInput got validated
enter image description here
Here is my code
DivisiSalesForm.vue


<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'
import { defineVaStepperSteps } from 'vuestic-ui'
import { useLoadingStore } from '@/stores/loading-store'
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'
import ToastService from '@/services/ui/ToastService'
import Step1DivisiSales from './Step1DivisiSales.vue'
import DivisiSalesService from '@/services/api/divisiSalesService'
import { Division } from '../types'

const loadingStore = useLoadingStore()
const isLoading = ref(false)

const router = useRouter()

const props = defineProps({
  id: {
    type: Number,
    required: false,
    default: null,
  },
  isEditMode: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
})

const bodyData = ref({
  name: '',
  id_company: null as number | null,
  division_principle: [],
})

const handleInputDataUpdate = (data: any) => {
  bodyData.value.name = data
}

const handlePrincipalDataUpdate = (data: any) => {
  console.log(`====: handlePrincipalDataUpdate`, data)
  bodyData.value.division_principle = data
}

const handleCompanyDataUpdate = (data: any) => {
  // console.log(`====: handleCompanyDataUpdate`, data)
  bodyData.value.id_company = data.value
}

const validateAndSubmit = async () => {
  const isStep1Valid = await step1Ref.value.validate()
  if (!isStep1Valid) {
    ToastService.showErrorToast('Please fill in all required fields.')
    return
  }
  await submit()
}

const submit = async () => {
  const step1Valid = await step1Ref.value?.validate()
  if (step1Valid) {
    console.log(`====: divisi sales form validated`)
  } else {
    console.log(`====: divisi sales form failed to validated`)
  }
  const body: Omit<Division, 'id'> = {
    ...bodyData.value,
  }
  loadingStore.startLoading()
  try {
    if (props.isEditMode) {
      console.log(`====: bodyData`, bodyData.value)
      await DivisiSalesService.update(props.id, body)
      console.log(`====: submit Edit`, body)
      ToastService.showSuccessToast('Divisi sales berhasil diperbarui')
    } else {
      await DivisiSalesService.create(body)
      console.log(`====: body`, body)
      ToastService.showSuccessToast('Divisi sales berhasil dibuat')
    }
    router.push({ name: 'divisi_sales_list' })
  } catch (error) {
    ToastService.showErrorToast('Terjadi kesalahan saat menyimpan data. Coba lagi.')
  } finally {
    loadingStore.stopLoading()
  }
}

const currentStep = ref(0)
const isLastStep = () => currentStep.value === steps.value.length - 1

// const form1Ref = ref()
// const step1Form = useForm(form1Ref)

const step1Ref = ref()

const steps = ref(
  defineVaStepperSteps([
    {
      label: 'Nama dan principal',
      beforeLeave: async (step) => {
        step.hasError = !step1Ref.value.validate()
      },
    },
    // {
    //   label: 'Pilih item',
    //   beforeLeave: async (step) => {
    //     const isValid = await step1Form.validateAsync()
    //     step.hasError = !isValid
    //   },
    // },
  ]),
)

const data = ref({ inputName: '', company: {} as any, principals: [] as any })

onMounted(async () => {
  if (props.isEditMode && props.id) {
    loadingStore.startLoading()
    isLoading.value = true
    try {
      const response = (await DivisiSalesService.getById(props.id)).data
      data.value = {
        inputName: response.name || '',
        principals: response.division_principle,
        company: response.company,
      }
      bodyData.value.name = response.name || ''
      bodyData.value.division_principle = response.division_principle as any
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to fetch outlet data:', error)
    } finally {
      loadingStore.stopLoading()
      isLoading.value = false
    }
  }
})
</script>

Step1DivisiSales.vue
<template>
  <VaForm ref="formRef">
    <div class="form-title">
      <h1 class="text-base">Nama dan prinsipal</h1>
    </div>
    <VaInput
      v-model="inputData"
      label="Nama divisi"
      placeholder="Masukkan nama divisi sales"
      color="primary"
      class="text-sm mb-4 custom-input"
      :rules="[(v) => !!v || 'Nama divisi required']"
      required-mark
      @input="onTestingDataChange"
    />
    <CompanySelect
      v-model="selectedCompany"
      class="custom-select mb-4"
      :rules="[(v: string) => !!v || 'Company is required']"
      required-mark
      @update:modelValue="onCompanyDataChange"
    />
    <h1 class="text-sm">Prinsipal</h1>
    <div v-for="(principal, index) in principals" :key="index">
      <PrincipalSelect
        ref="principalSelectRef"
        :principal="principal"
        :index="index"
        :company-name="companyName"
        :disabled="!companyName"
        class="custom-select mb-4"
        required-mark
        :rules="[(v: string) => !!v || 'At least one principal is required']"
        @update="onPrincipalUpdateChange"
        @remove="removeSelect"
      />
    </div>
    <VaButton preset="secondary" border-color="primary" class="custom-button full-width" @click="addPrincipal">
      Tambah Principal
    </VaButton>
  </VaForm>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, defineEmits, watch } from 'vue'
import CompanySelect from '@/components/company/CompanySelect.vue'
import PrincipalSelect from './PrincipalSelect.vue'
import { Select } from '@/components/select/types'

const props = defineProps({
  inputName: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
  },
  principalsData: {
    type: Array,
    default: () => [],
  },
  company: {
    type: Object,
    default: () => ({}),
  },
})

const principals = ref([{ id_principle: '', name: '' }]) // Ensure there is one principal by default

const emit = defineEmits(['update:inputData', 'update:principalData', 'update:companyData'])
const inputData = ref('')
const selectedCompany = ref<Select | undefined>({
  text: '',
  value: null,
})
const companyName = ref<string>()

const onTestingDataChange = () => {
  emit('update:inputData', inputData.value)
}

const onPrincipalUpdateChange = ({ index, principal }: { index: number; principal: any }) => {
  principals.value[index].id_principle = principal.id_principle
  principals.value[index].name = principal.name

  emit('update:principalData', principals.value)
}

const onCompanyDataChange = () => {
  companyName.value = selectedCompany.value?.text
  emit('update:companyData', selectedCompany.value)
}

const formRef = ref()
const principalSelectRef = ref(null)
// const validate = () => formRef.value?.validate()

const addPrincipal = () => {
  principals.value.push({ id_principle: '', name: '' })
}

const removeSelect = (index: number) => {
  principals.value.splice(index, 1)
}

watch(
  () => props.principalsData,
  (newInputData) => {
    principals.value = newInputData.length ? newInputData : [{ id_principle: '', name: '' }]
  },
  { immediate: true },
)

watch(
  () => props.inputName,
  (newInputData) => {
    inputData.value = newInputData
  },
  { immediate: true },
)

watch(
  () => props.company,
  (data) => {
    selectedCompany.value = { text: data.name, value: data.id }
    companyName.value = selectedCompany.value?.text
  },
  { immediate: true },
)

const validate = async () => {
  const formValid = await formRef.value?.validate()
  console.log(`====: formRef.value`, formRef.value)
  console.log(`====: formValid`, formValid)
  return formValid
}

defineExpose({ validate })

CompanySelect.vue
<template>
  <VaSelect
    v-model="localSelectedCompany"
    :options="companyOptions"
    :label="label"
    :placeholder="placeholder"
    track-by="value"
    searchable
    highlight-matched-text
  />
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import CompanyService from '@/services/api/companyService'
import { onMounted, ref, watch } from 'vue'
import { VaSelect } from 'vuestic-ui'
import { Select } from '@/components/select/types'

const companyOptions = ref<Select[]>([])
const localSelectedCompany = ref<object | null>(null)

const props = defineProps({
  modelValue: {
    type: Object,
    default: null,
  },
  placeholder: {
    type: String,
    default: 'Pilih company',
  },
  label: {
    type: String,
    default: 'Company',
  },
})

const emit = defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])

watch(
  () => props.modelValue,
  (newValue) => {
    localSelectedCompany.value = newValue
  },
  { immediate: true },
)

watch(localSelectedCompany, (newValue) => {
  emit('update:modelValue', newValue)
})

const fetchCompanies = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await CompanyService.list({ perPage: 100 })
    companyOptions.value = response.data.map((company) => ({
      text: company.name,
      value: company.id,
    }))
    if (props.modelValue) {
      localSelectedCompany.value = props.modelValue
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching companies:', error)
  }
}

onMounted(() => {
  fetchCompanies()
})
</script>


What goes wrong here?
Thank you
I already give the rules on CompanySelect but nothing works for the validate.
I expect the rules will show up if hte CompanySelect is null or not selected
